# Einstein Streaming Updates through API not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, einstein, postman, einstein-recommendations

I know there is another question out there similar to mine.  When I make the Postman call, I receive a 401 error (unauthorized).  I've checked the API_Key.  Is this related to the whitelisting required and if so, what domains should be whitelisted for Postman use.

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

Answer (score 0):

In Admin >> Implementation >> Domain

You need to have any domain registered here that you are using in the url field

[image]

Comment: I thought I had done that, yet it's still not allowing.  Could you provide what domains you used for Postman, screenshots please if possible?

Comment: in this case in postman my url was https://www.google.com in your case you would need to add cat.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the allowlist includes the domain of the links you are passing in the "URL" field.